# Tie-breakers in the group

Tags: rules, football, tie-breaker

The ranking of each team in each group shall be determined as follows:

a) greatest number of points obtained in all group matches;
b) goal difference in all group matches;
c) greatest number of goals scored in all group matches.

If two or more teams are equal on the basis of the above three criteria, their rankings shall be determined as follows:

d) greatest number of points obtained in the group matches between the teams concerned;
e) goal difference resulting from the group matches between the teams concerned;
f) greater number of goals scored in all group matches between the teams concerned;
g) drawing of lots by the FIFA Organising Committee.

**I want to ask about the following case, based on above rules:**
A vs B: 1-2
B vs C: 0-1
A vs D: 6-0
A vs C: 2-0
C vs D: 6-0
B vs D: 5-0

The table looks like this:
A: 6 point, 9 scored, 2 against
B: 6 point, 7 scored, 2 against
C: 6 point, 7 scored, 2 against
D: 0 point, 0 scored, 17 against

**How to determine the first, second, and third positioned team in the group. I need to know it because two top teams will qualify to semifinal.**

Comment: How to determine the qualified teams? You follow the procedure you've detailed - which bit of it don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, **rule-a** tells us who's the 4-th placed team in the group:

> a) greatest number of points obtained in all group matches;

It's team D with the least points (0 points).

Now rule-a doesn't help us to determine first 3 positions in the table as all three teams (A, B, C) have 6 points. That's why we move to **rule-b**, which states:

> b) goal difference in all group matches;

Out of 3 teams in question, team A has the best goal difference `(9 - 2 = 7)`, so team A is ranked first.

As Team B and Team C have equal goal differences `(7 - 2 = 5)`, rule-b doesn't help us in breaking the tie between these teams, hence we move to **rule-c**:

> c) greatest number of goals scored in all group matches.

But rule-c doesn't help us either, as both teams have scored 7 goals each. We move to **rule-d**. *Remember, the teams in question are Team B and Team C.* rule-d states:

> d) greatest number of points obtained in the group matches between the
>   teams concerned;

Only 1 match has been played between teams concerned and Team C has won it. So, it's Team C which will be ranked second and Team B which will be ranked 3rd.

Hence, the final rankings are as follows:

1. Team A
2. Team C
3. Team B
4. Team D

So, Team A and Team C will qualify.